# how to extract a matrix and a vector from a vector

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, vector-calculus

I have a vector like this:

```
V = {a*exp1+b*exp2+c*exp3, a*exp4+b*exp5+c*exp6, a*exp7+b*exp8+c*exp9}
```

and I want to get :

> ```
> mat = {{exp1, exp2, exp3}, {exp4, exp5, exp6}, {exp7, exp8, exp9}}
> ```

from vector

```
var = {a, b, c}
```

so : `mat.var === V`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Coefficient:

```
var = {a, b, c}
V = {a*exp1+b*exp2+c*exp3, a*exp4+b*exp5+c*exp6, a*exp7+b*exp8+c*exp9}    
Transpose[Map[Coefficient[V, #] &, var]]
```

> ```
> {{exp1, exp2, exp3}, {exp4, exp5, exp6}, {exp7, exp8, exp9}}
> ```

Comment: Thats the solution Thanks!
In case of Vector is in form:
V = {{a*exp1+b*exp2+c*exp3}, {a*exp4+b*exp5+c*exp6}, {a*exp7+b*exp8+c*exp9}} 
Use
Reshape[list_, dimensions_] := 
  First[Fold[Partition[#1, #2] &, Flatten[list], 
    Reverse[dimensions]]];
  Reshape[Transpose[Map[Coefficient[V, #] &, var]],{3,3}]

Answer (score 2):

You want [`CoefficientArrays`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CoefficientArrays.html):

```
CoefficientArrays[V, var] // Last // Normal
```

> ```
> {{exp1, exp2, exp3}, {exp4, exp5, exp6}, {exp7, exp8, exp9}}
> ```